# How do I turn on 'shutdown logging' or operating system tracing?

Tags: xorg, shutdown, logging

I have a simple question: how do I turn on logging of the shutdown sequence and X-server, which both keep failing; shutdown that doesn't shut it down, XServer that crashes.

I would like to create the equivalent of a windows memory dump, the windows event viewer's System-bucket and a crash-dump on SIGTERM for XServer.

Regards

Comment: Try looking into `/var/log/`.

Comment: but what am I looking for in these logs? how can I tell what's an error, what's info and what's debug information? care to make your comment a reply and explain a bit about /var/log?

Answer (score 1):

This may help with creating a program dump or catching a crash:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

Comment: indeed it might, but would you mind expanding on how you think it would? like an overview of how it is done?